# How to access an index in a 2d list and change it's value in scheme/racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

[image]I have the following empty list (empty in the sense that everything is initialized to dash)

((- - -)(- - -)(- - -))

And I wish to access a specific index within this list (say 0,1) and set it to say 1

((- 1 -)(- - -)(- - -))

How can this be done in scheme?

Comment: Have you considered using a vector of vectors instead of a list of lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In racket, you can use [`for/list`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/for.html#(form._((lib._racket/private/base..rkt)._for/list))) to accumulate the results into a list.

`e` is each element in a `row` (list) while `i`, `j` keep track of indexing position in `l`.

```
;; [Listof [Listof Any]] Nat Nat Any -> [Listof [Listof Any]]
;; changes the element at (`x`, `y`) position in `l` to `to`
(define (change-at l x y to)
  (for/list ([row l] [i (length l)])
    (for/list ([e row] [j (length row)])
      (if (and (= x i) (= y j))
          to
          e))))

(change-at '((- - -) (- - -) (- - -)) 0 1 1)
;; => '((- 1 -) (- - -) (- - -))
```

Comment: are you using `#lang racket`?

Comment: yes i am...it works but when i change my list (change-at myList 0 1 1), it doesn't seem to update myList

Comment: i have added a screenshot of my code and console printout

Comment: Ah, it's not *mutating* table, it's returning a new list altogether. so use `(display (change-at table 0 1 1))`

Comment: so would i need to declare a new variable (using let) to keep the new table? what do you exactly mean it's not a mutating table? how can i keep the original table without declaring new variables?

Comment: You can use `(set! table (change-at! table 0 1 1))` to assign the result to  your  existing `table`. Assignments do not create new bindings, but change the existing ones. Note that the result of `set!` itself is `#<void>`, but it changes *state*, so `!` at the end of the function warns you that it has a side-effect.

Note that although sometimes useful, mutation can lead to a [performance hit](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/performance.html#%28part._.Mutation_and_.Performance%29). However, In this case it's best to use the traditional mutable array: `vector`.